# I'm creating a contact application. Is there any other thing that I should create?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm creating the app using Eclipse Kepler...I've created 3 database in Eclipse- database, entity and UI. In database, it contains ContactDAO,UserDAO and DBManager(for database connection) . In Entity, it contains Contact and User. In UI, it contains ContactAdd, COntactDetails , ContactList, LoginFrame and MenuFrame JFrames. Now, I'm stuck at ContactList frame... it contains ComboBox and I've tried to run it but I can't get the names... this is the code:

```
public class ContactList extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtSearch;
    private JComboBox cbContactNames;
    private MenuFrame parentFrame;
    private Contact selContact;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ContactList frame = new ContactList(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ContactList(MenuFrame f) {
        this.parentFrame = f;
        setTitle("Personal Assistant");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        txtSearch = new JTextField();
        txtSearch.setBounds(22, 11, 294, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtSearch);
        txtSearch.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("Search");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                searchContact();

            }
        });
        btnSearch.setBounds(326, 10, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSearch);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name");
        lblName.setBounds(42, 88, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblName);

        cbContactNames = new JComboBox();
        cbContactNames.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED)
                {
                    if (cbContactNames.getSelectedIndex()>0){
                        String name=(String)cbContactNames.getSelectedItem();
                        selContact=ContactDAO.findContactByName(name); //adjusted
                        showContact();

                    }
                }
                }


        });
        ArrayList<Contact> ContactList=ContactDAO.getAllContacts();
        cbContactNames.addItem("--Select Name--");
        for (int i=0; i<ContactList.size(); i++)
        {
            Contact contact = ContactList.get(i);
            cbContactNames.addItem(contact.getName());
        }

        cbContactNames.setBounds(87, 85, 229, 20);
        contentPane.add(cbContactNames);

        JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
        btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                goBack();
            }

        });
        btnClose.setBounds(158, 203, 89, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnClose);
    }

    private void goBack() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parentFrame.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }


    private void showContact() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ContactDetails contactdetails=new ContactDetails(this,selContact);
        contactdetails.setVisible(true);
        this.setVisible(false);

    }

    private void searchContact() {
        String name=txtSearch.getText();
        if (name!=null){
            selContact=ContactDAO.findContactByName(txtSearch.getText());
        }
        showContact();
    }
}
```

Then, I have also created the ContactDetails frame that contains the contact details, edit save and close buttons, and Delete label set as Image. The project says when the edit button is clicked, the save button will be visible... I don't know how to do that...Here's my code :

```
public class ContactDetails extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField txtName;
    private JTextField txtMobile;
    private JTextField txtHome;
    private JTextField txtEmail;
    private JButton btnEdit;
    private JButton btnSave;
    private ContactList parentFrame;
    private Contact contact;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    ContactDetails frame = new ContactDetails(null,null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public ContactDetails(ContactList f,Contact c) {
        this.parentFrame = f;
        this.contact=c;
        setTitle("Contact Details");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JLabel lblImage = new JLabel("");
        lblImage.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ContactDetails.class.getResource("/images/kitty.png")));
        lblImage.setBounds(34, 28, 79, 70);
        contentPane.add(lblImage);

        JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name:");
        lblName.setBounds(119, 48, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblName);

        txtName = new JTextField(contact.getName());
        txtName.setBounds(162, 45, 169, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtName);
        txtName.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblMobile = new JLabel("Mobile:");
        lblMobile.setBounds(119, 93, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblMobile);

        txtMobile = new JTextField();
        txtMobile.setBounds(162, 90, 169, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtMobile);
        txtMobile.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblHome = new JLabel("Home:");
        lblHome.setBounds(119, 141, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblHome);

        txtHome = new JTextField();
        txtHome.setBounds(162, 138, 169, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtHome);
        txtHome.setColumns(10);

        JLabel lblEmail = new JLabel("Email:");
        lblEmail.setBounds(119, 186, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(lblEmail);

        txtEmail = new JTextField();
        txtEmail.setBounds(162, 183, 169, 20);
        contentPane.add(txtEmail);
        txtEmail.setColumns(10);

        JButton btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                contactAdded();
            }

        });
        btnSave.setBounds(184, 227, 74, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnSave);

        JButton btnEdit = new JButton("Edit");
        btnEdit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                editContact();
            }
        });
        btnEdit.setBounds(110, 227, 74, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnEdit);

        JButton btnClose = new JButton("Close");
        btnClose.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                goBack();
            }
        });
        btnClose.setBounds(257, 227, 74, 23);
        contentPane.add(btnClose);

        JLabel lblDelete = new JLabel("");
        lblDelete.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                removeContact();
            }


        });
        lblDelete.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ContactDetails.class.getResource("/images/trush.png")));
        lblDelete.setBounds(365, 28, 46, 54);
        contentPane.add(lblDelete);
    }
    private void contactAdded() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name=txtName.getText();
        String mobile=txtMobile.getText();
        String home=txtHome.getText();
        String email=txtEmail.getText();

        Contact contact = new Contact(name, mobile, home, email);
        if(ContactDAO.create(contact)){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Contact successfull saved!");

        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Contact not save!");
        }
    }

    private void goBack() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        parentFrame.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();

    }
    private void removeContact() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name=txtName.getText();
        String mobile=txtMobile.getText();
        String home=txtHome.getText();
        String email=txtEmail.getText();

        Contact contact = new Contact(name, mobile, home, email);
        if(ContactDAO.delete(contact)){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Contact deleted");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Contact delete unsuccessful");
        }

    }
    private void editContact() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String name=txtName.getText();
        String mobile=txtMobile.getText();
        String home=txtHome.getText();
        String email=txtEmail.getText();

        Contact contact = new Contact(name, mobile, home, email);
        if (ContactDAO.update(contact)){

          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Contact successfully updated");

    }
     else { 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(contentPane, "Contact update unsuccessful");

    }
    }
}
```

Also, the Save button is tricky for me... It seems that after clicking the Save button, a message should pop up for confirmation that should include (OK) button. When the (ok)button is clicked,  Save button will be disabled and Edit button will be enabled again. All Text fields will be disabled. The (Delete Icon button) also needs a prompt box that includes (Yes, no and cancel) buttons. If confirm, contact will be deleted and user will be brought back to the contacts list frame... How should I do it?

Tell me if I have to create another JFrame or DAO...

Comment: The code you have posted is completely unrelated to your question in my opinion. To get better answers please be as specific as possible and only post relevant information (and use a meaningful title as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need somthing like this for your save button and same for remove button:

```
    int showConfirmDialog = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(new JFrame(), "Approve?","Title",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
    if(showConfirmDialog == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        btnSave.setEnabled(false);
        btnEdit.setEnabled(true);
        txtName.setEnabled(false);
        //other fields
    } else {
        //If no or cancel actions
    }
```

Read [tutorial for dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Watch [`showConfirmDialog(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object%29)